# Specifying Request Handler for Solr Join

Tags: join, solr, requesthandler

I am using Solr 4.5.1. This is the syntax for a join query:

```
q=blue&fq={!join fromIndex=core1 toIndex=core2 from=field1 to=field2} city:nyc
```

If I want core1 (fromIndex) to use a different request handler(other than the default), how do I specify that?

To give more details: Both core1 and core2 are like virtual cores(I hope I am not misusing the terminology here) that use shards behind the scenes. I could not specify shards for the default request handler for those virtual cores because doing so causes infinite loops at the time of startup. Hence the need for non-default request handlers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to use alternative request handler? Most of the features (format, etc) do not apply.